# How to read in input from the user in char?

Tags: java, char, bufferedreader

when I input character the output is displayed as wrong input. I don't understand what's wrong. The input given in the compiler is uppercase letter E or D but when it complies in switch case the default case runs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     //Scanner
    //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int q = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    char c;
    int i=0, j=0;
    int id=0, jd=0;
    int arr[][] = new int[q][q];
    int temp[][] = new int[q][q];
    for(int ip=0; ip<q; ip++)
    {
        c = (char)br.read();
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'E': 
                    for(int al=i; al<i+1; al++)
                    {
                        for(int al2=j; al2<j++; al2++)
                        {
                        arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  
                        }
                    }

                    }
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    break;

            case 'D':
                     System.out.println(arr[id][jd]);
                     id++;
                     jd++;
                     break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("wrong input");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the default branch can you print `"wrong input, c = " + c` to see what the actual value is?

Comment: 1. It seems, that `case 'D'` is placed outside switch statement  2. If you need to get only uppercase letters, you can use `Character.toUpperCase()` method - or just add lowercase `case` labels.

Comment: In the switch statement, much of case E is outside the switch. You need to check your parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

> **tldr**: Use `c = br.readLine().charAt(0)` instead of `c = (char)br.read()` in your `for` loop to read `char`.

---

If you try to run it with `q = 1` and then with `char c = 'E'` as input it works as expected.

But the same with `q = 2`, the default case executes and so forth for other values of `q`.

Because when you type `E` or `D` and press `enter`, the programs reads `\r\n`, so `\r` for the second and then `\n` for the third iteration.

Hence it's advisable to use `br.readLine().charAt(0)` so that you can read the `char` line by line.

The full code will be as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     //Scanner
    //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int q = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    char c;
    int i=0, j=0;
    int id=0, jd=0;
    int arr[][] = new int[q][q];
    int temp[][] = new int[q][q];
    for(int ip=0; ip<q; ip++)
    {
        c = br.readLine().charAt(0);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'E': 
                    for(int al=i; al<i+1; al++)
                    {
                        for(int al2=j; al2<j++; al2++)
                        {
                        arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  
                        }
                    }
                    //an extra closing bracket was put here by OP at first
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    break;

            case 'D':
                     System.out.println(arr[id][jd]);
                     id++;
                     jd++;
                     break;
            default:
                    System.out.println(c);
                    System.out.println("wrong input");
        }
    } // one } was missing here too.
}
```